# removing elements of the environment using a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have 16 elements in the environment called Factor1 to Factor16. I would like to remove them automatically. I wrote that and I cannot understand why that's not working...

```
 for(i in 1:16) {
    rm(paste0('Factor',i))
  }
```

sorry for this basic question, I am a beginner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:16) {
    rm(list=paste0('Factor',i))
  }
```

although `rm(list=paste0('Factor',1:16))` or `rm(list=ls(pattern="Factor"))`would be more appropriate...

Comment: thanks again. Wasn't aware of list function. With that no loop needed. Although it was paste0 in my case.

Comment: Sure, I found out latter using your answer. Edited ;)